# Delete entire database with severals table in code inside sql android

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I've a database (BASE2.db) with 4 tables inside, but, when i want to delete the database i've an error:

the code:

```
db.execSQL("DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS BASE2.db");
```

the logcat:

```
(1) near "DATABASE": syntax error
```

I've try this, but not correct:

```
db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS BASE2.db");
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

> this.deleteDatabase("databasename.db");

where `this` refers to your Activity, or any Context.

for more refer this blog

> http://logcatsolutions.blogspot.in/2012/07/sqlite-complete-example-create.html

Answer (score 2):

Try to use the following:

```
context.deleteDatabase(databaseName.db);
```

Comment: but how to know the databsae path if the appli is moved to the sd card?